# What is the communication protocol for the side-stick in the F-16 or F/A-18?

Tags: flight-controls, avionics, f-16, fa-18, sidestick

The side-stick in the F-16 or F/A-18 communicates with the flight control computer to transmit the pilot inputs. This transmission uses a protocol. Which protocol?

Comment: There is no side stick on an F/A-18 Hornet.

Comment: No side stick as mentioned and they are analogue signals in at least the F/A-18 A B C D. Discrete signals for the buttons. Protocol to me would imply some sort of digital databus tech such as 1553 or ARINC 629, and that isn't how this is done. It uses LVDTs.